# Rendering a form to a block

Tags: forms

I have created a block named 'xyz'. I also created a form whose id is 'form-type-node-form' and i want this form to display in that block. How can i do this?
please help me to get solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that in couple of ways. You can create custom module or simply by using on the modules mentioned below.

[Advanced Form Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/afb)

> With this module you can do the following:
>
> 1) Create any number of blocks with a particular node edit form.
>
> 2) create any number of blocks with a particular node add form of a
>   content type.
>
> 3) Create as many blocks as you like of each kind.
>
> 4) From the content type choose which fields to display on a per block
>   basis.However required fields will be automatically displayed.
>
> 5) All forms will be saved through ajax. So multiple node forms can be
>   independently placed on a single page and worked with simultaneously.

OR

[Form Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/formblock)

> Enables the presentation of user registration, site wide contact, or node creation forms in blocks. This is particularly useful for including forms on panels.

OR

You can also achieve that by creating custom module. Follow this [link](http://sanchiz.net/en/blog/drupal-7-display-node-form-block-node-form-image-field-or-file-field)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [drupal_get_form](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/drupal_get_form/7) function to get form, example:

```
function MYMODULE_block_view($delta = '') {

  $block = array();

  switch ($delta) {
    case 'xyz':
      $block['subject'] = t('XYZ');
      $block['content'] = drupal_get_form('FORM_ID');
      break;
  }
  return $block;
}
```

Comment: i have done this..but it is not working..

Comment: @user35790 what is the name of your form function?

Comment: function mymodule_block_view

Comment: @user35790 `drupal_get_form` will get `mymodule_block_view` as a form id then..

Comment: it is working if i create a custom block..but it is not working with a block if i add block from structure in drupal